# How can I refresh the position of a Slider with Scroll event?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, slider, scaletransform

I'm now tryin to scaling a image with mouse-wheel cmd.
and have some problems with refresh the position of slider position.

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1">
    <Slider x:Name="slider_value" Value="{Binding Scale, Mode=TwoWay}" Maximum="3" Minimum="1"/>
</Grid>


<Other Grid>
        <target obj want to scale>
        <Grid.LayoutTransform>
            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="{Binding ElementName=slider_value, Path=Value}"
                            ScaleY="{Binding ElementName=slider_value, Path=Value}"/>
        </Grid.LayoutTransform>
</Other Grid>
```

MainViewModel.cs

```
 private void ExecuteZoom(MouseWheelEventArgs e) {

        if(e.Delta > 0) {
            if(Scale>=3)
                return;
            Scale += 0.1;
        }
        if(e.Delta < 0) {
            if(Scale<=1)
                return;
            Scale -= 0.1;
        }
        //((MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow).UpdateLayout();
        //i thought this can be solved by  above code but don't work
        Debug.Print($"{Scale}");
    }
```

I checked

1. the value of var Scale varies successfully with mouseWheel
2. the value of var Scale varies successfully with moving slider
3. the scale of target varies with slider moved by "Manually"
4. the value of var Scale successfully is changed 
   but the position of slider isn't affected, and also ScaleTransForm doesnt work.

thanks!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MEYR5.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yJQd.png)

Comment: Does the property "Scale" raise PropertyChanged ?

Comment: @Babbillumpa Thanks! you're genius!